# How to set Model id to a string in Loopback?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, loopback

I have a string that can be used to uniquely identify a Model instance, e.g., email - john@doe.com, which can be assigned to only one instance in the database, which means it won't be duped.

Now, how can I make this string from a variable to be assigned to a newly created instance automatically on creation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just found it in the docs:

> In database terms, ID properties are primary key column(s) are. Such properties are defined with the 'id' attribute set to true or a number as the position for a composite key.

```
{
    "myId": {
    "type": "string", 
    "id": true 
  }
}
```